# python print only one empty line after loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to print only one empty line after each loop. But my code print two empty lines.

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print(i, j)
    print('\n')
```

Expected output:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
#ony one empty line
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
print()
```

instead of

```
print('\n')
```

because `print` automatically prints a new line due to `end="\n"` parameter of it; that's why you're printing two newlines.